# IntelliJ IDEA plugin development - Log from within plugin

Tags: java, logging, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

How can I log something for debugging purpose from within a IntelliJ plugin?
(I'm **not** using *Community Edition*)

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Why do you need to log from a plugin? Can't you use dedicated logging library from inside your codebase? Or do you want to write your own plugin?

Comment: I'm writing my own plugin. I just want to log something somewhere in my code and see the logged value.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger` is the officially recommended logger to use for IntelliJ plugin development. See this for more details: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5306410#5306410

The thread is old so some of the other information might be outdated, that class still exists and should be used for logging.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855314/idea-intellij-plugin-not-working-in-android-studio-1-5-1

Comment: I use this to instantiate it: `private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getInstance(MyClass.class);`

Comment: Just to add this for others: the log lines would appear in the idea.log of the sandbox in which your plugin is running. You can find log files under `<sandbox_directory>/system/log/` directory. Sandbox directory is configured by gradle-intellij-plugin and points to `<project_dir>/build/idea-sandbox` by default.

Comment: gurupal2000 is there a way to update this file? I want to log my statements in a specified folder so that if something breaks for my user I can ask them to share this log file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that [this](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/platform/util-rt/src/com/intellij/openapi/diagnostic/LoggerRt.java) will be helpful. It is a wrapper that provides logging based on IDEA internals or `java.util.logging` (if internals aren't available).